# How to refer to the variable stored by the structure, which is also part of other structs

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to learn how to use structures, but I'm stuck with (probably very simple) problem. How do I refer to variable x, which is stored by the structure POINT, which belongs RECT structure? Beginnings are always difficult for me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    

struct Point {
    int x, y;
};

struct Rect {
    Point bottom_left, top_right;
};

void printPoint(const Point* p){
    cout << "(" << p->x << "," << p->y << ")";
}

void printRect(const Rect* r){
    cout << "["; printPoint(&r->top_right);
    cout << ","; printPoint(&r->bottom_left);
    cout << "]" << endl;
}

bool haveIntersection(const Rect* r1, const Rect* r2){
    cout << &r1->bottom_left->x;
}


int main() {
    Rect r1 = { {1,1}, {4,3} };
    Rect r2 = { {2,0}, {3,4} };
    Rect r3 = { {0,4}, {1,5} };
    printRect(&r1);
    haveIntersection(&r1, &r2);
}
```

Comment: Instead of &r->top_right, I would prefer &(r->top_right) to avoid confusion regarding operator precedence. Also, &r1->bottom_left->x is not correct.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal i got problem wit this  &r1->bottom_left->x. How should it looks like to get access to x variable?

Comment: (r1->bottom_left).x or ((*r1).bottom_left).x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your struct are

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
};

struct Rect {
    Point bottom_left, top_right;
};
```

If you declare **Rect** object:

```
Rect rectangle;
Rect* rectanglePtr = new Rect();
```

You can access the x,y values in this way:

```
rectangle.bottom_left.x;  
rectanglePtr->bottom_left.x;
```

## edit

in your case, **haveIntersection** become:

```
bool haveIntersection(const Rect* r1, const Rect* r2) {
    /* Warning: you aren't using r2 var and return nothing */
    cout << (r1->bottom_left).x;
}
```

Comment: I got problem with bool haveIntersection(). Can You look at it? Becouse i have probably forgot about pointer or something, but i really have no idea what is wrong there. All i want is get access to x variable, but this is not correct &r1->bottom_left->x.

Comment: THANKS! its such an easy thing and i have already wasted 2 hours for it. Yes, i know that im not returning anything from r2, but its only start and i have already stucked. You are my hero :).

Answer (score 2):

Simply like this `r1.bottom_left.x`

Notice that `r1.bottom_left` returns a `Point&`. Therefor you can just work with it like any other `Point`